# How to calculate confidence interval for the residual variance in ANCOVA models?

Tags: confidence-interval, variance, residuals, ancova

As the question states I need to know how to calculate this.

Given variable $Y$ and $X$ with $\operatorname{cor}(Y,x)=r$, the residual variance is:

$$(1-r^2)\cdot\sigma_Y^2,$$

which represents the variance that can not be explained by covariable $X$.

How is the CI for this defined, or how could I derive it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model: $Y=\alpha + \beta X +\epsilon$ and $\epsilon \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$

Residual is defined as $e = Y-\hat Y = Y-\hat \alpha -\hat \beta X$

The $\sigma^2$ is estimated by $\hat \sigma^2 = \frac {\sum_{i=1}^ne^2}{n-2}$

We know that $\frac {\hat \sigma^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \chi^2_{n-2}$.

So find the corresponding percentiles $L, U$ of $\chi^2_{n-2}$, and you can get

$L\le\frac {\hat \sigma^2}{\sigma^2}\le U$

$\frac {\hat \sigma^2}U \le \sigma^2 \le \frac {\hat \sigma^2}L$

Comment: Can you use this interval in this situation still? I was unsure because $\epsilon$ is depended on two random variables. This would mean that the only thing changing are the d.f.?

Comment: Yes. df changes to n-3.

Comment: In the answer the correct statement should be "We know that $ n*\hat{\sigma}^2/\sigma^2 \hspace{0.2cm} \tilde{} \hspace{0.2cm} \chi^2_{n-2}. $